# setTimeout OR setInterval, Excecute POC after 3 seconds only once not repeatative

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to execute some piece of code 3 seconds after when I click on button. I have tried using `setInterval` and `setTimeout` but by observing it, I found that they repetitively executes the code but I want just once.

```
function stoptimer(data) {

    $('.stop-btn').each(function () {
        var wait = $(this).data('key');
        if (timerData[wait]['timerId'] != null) {
            clearInterval(timerData[wait]['timerId']);
            if (timerData[data]['timerId'] != timerData[wait]['timerId']) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    timer(wait, timerData[wait]['remaining'], global_interval, global_timer_interval)
                }, 3000);

             //^^ I want to execute this timeout only once not at every 3 seconds.
            }
        }
    });
    timerData[data]['timerId'] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change your code from

```
setTimeout(function () {
            timer(wait, timerData[wait]['remaining'], global_interval, global_timer_interval)
        }, 3000);
```

to

```
timerData[wait]['timerId']=setInterval(function () {
            timer(wait, timerData[wait]['remaining'], global_interval, global_timer_interval)
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your guess! But it not helped me. Actually my code works fine for first time click on stop button but not working on next clicks on stop button

Comment: Looks like your code must be like this:
if (timerData[wait]['timerId'] != null) {
            clearInterval(timerData[wait]['timerId']);
}
else {
timerData[wait]['timerId']=setInterval(function () {
            timer(wait, timerData[wait]['remaining'], global_interval, global_timer_interval)
        }, 3000);
}